Rails.logger not working in ApplicationJob.before_perform
I'm using ActiveJob to manage my jobs, and I have the following ApplicationJob:
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  # [...]

  before_perform do |job|
    Rails.logger.info 'before_perform callback triggered' # This doesn't log
  end

  # [...]
end

Additionally, I have another job that inherits from ApplicationJob:
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform
    # do something
    Rails.logger.info 'perform method called' # This logs correctly
  end
end

I've configured my logger to write to a file, and while the logs inside the perform method are written to the file as expected, the logs from the before_perform callback don't appear at all.
For context, I'm invoking the jobs using both perform_now and perform_later methods, but neither seems to trigger the before_perform log.
Thanks in advance!

Did you check if the before_perform callback is getting called?

Yes, puts works.

That seems odd. You could output Rails.logger in both variants to check if they point to the same logging device and Rails.logger.level which should be <= 1.

call puts Rails.logger.inspect, maybe it's reconfigured somewhere for ActiveJob, and it's outputting to some other file?

While I can't explain the behavior, there are 2 things you could try.
Option 1 is to use Sidekiq.logger if Sidekiq is what runs the jobs.
Option 2 is to define logger inside the Job class, which is not too elegant, but does the job. Like so:
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  # [...]

  before_perform do |job|
    say 'before_perform callback triggered' # This should log into the job_runner.log
  end

  # [...]

  def say(what)
    unless @logger
      @logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'job_runner.log'))
    end

    @logger.info(what)
  end
end


For some reason, adding config.logger = Logger.new(file_path) in my config/application.rb worked. Thank you!
